# php string as byte array, hashed then base64 encoded

Tags: php

To generate an authentication header for an api connection, my code should follow these steps:

1. Create a string of the form [unique]:[apikey].
2. Convert string from step 1 to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding.
3. Compute the SHA-256 hash for the byte array from step 2.
4. Base64 encode the byte array computed in step 3; this string will be authentication key.

As far as I understand, strings in php *are* byte arrays, so my initial method looks like the following.

```
public function generateAuthKey()
{
    $unique = uniqid(); # unique string
    $string = $unique.':'.$this->apiKey; # step 1
    $string = utf8_encode($string); # step 2 ?
    $hash = hash('sha256', $string); # step 3
    $base64 = base64_encode($hash); # step 4

    return $base64;
}
```

My application which tries to connect using this auth key will receive a 403 error.

Does my code above complete the required steps (and perhaps there is an error in my api key) or is there some other way in php of following the steps to create the auth key?

Comment: i think it's working ok:-https://eval.in/841537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, strings in PHP *are* already byte arrays. And unless your `$string` contains any non-ASCII characters, it's also already valid UTF-8 (UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII); so you can skip the "encode as UTF-8" step.

Likely the algorithm is expecting the output of the hash to be binary, which you're then supposed to convert to base 64. By default `hash` returns hex values, not binary. For that you need to set its 3rd parameter. In summary:

```
$unique = uniqid();
$string = $unique . ':' . $this->apiKey;
$hash   = hash('sha256', $string, true);
$base64 = base64_encode($hash);
```

Of course, what you're supposed to do with `$unique` I don't know. Likely you're supposed to send that value together with the request as well, otherwise there's no way the server can validate the hash.

Comment: yes, unique and apikey are other headers (which didn't really add anything to question). adding the third parameter to the hash function made this work; many thanks @deceze.

Comment: also, of course, your name came up in the comments in the official docs when reading about this and related encodings for what i'm working on...

Comment: Just for reference, this is the way Expedia is validating it's API Authentication.